# Mail notifications continue to appear even when mail app is closed

Tags: email

When using a variety of email clients (Newton, Nylas), MacOS will still show notifications for incoming mail when the client has closed. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Your question doesn’t say anything about the reason, but if it’s because you need to share your screen locally or online for presentations (my personal use case for this need) you can use Do Not Disturb to temporarily halt all notification.

Answer (score 4):

Notifications for mail are designed to arrive whether the main app runs or not.

You can disable notifications for mail entirely, though - Go to System Preferences > Notifications and make sure the apps have their Notification settings turned off. In the example below, the DaisyDisk alert style has been set to None:

[image]

You can also uncheck all the checkboxes for more granular control of when you see (and hear) notifications.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to turn the notifications off within the client itself.

Here is Newton's steps:
http://help.newtonhq.com/article/how-do-i-configure-my-new-email-notifications/